# Covariant derivative of a Killing vector in static spacetime

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

In the book in which I am studying there is the following problem:

> Prove that in a static spacetime Eq. (3.7.14)($ds^2=-e^{2U}dt^2+h_{ij}dy^idy^j$) the Killing vector obeys the relation:
> $$\xi_{\mu ; \nu}=\xi_{\mu} w_{\nu}-\xi_{\nu} w_{\mu} $$ where $w_\nu = U_{;\nu}$ and $\xi^2= \xi^\alpha\xi_\alpha = -e^{2U}.$

What I have done is the following :

$\xi_{\mu ; \nu}=\xi_{\mu , \nu} + \Gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu \nu} \xi_\sigma \ \ , \ \  $

from which I don't really know how to go on.
It may be cause I am studying this by myself and I don't really know properly Killing vectors . Any help would be precious

Comment: Perhaps it would help to provide eq 3.7.14?

Comment: @mikestone done

Comment: You have to evaluate $\xi_{\mu;\nu} = \xi_{\mu,\nu} - \Gamma^\sigma_{\mu\nu} \xi_\sigma$. Take the given metric and work out all the components of the Christoffel symbol, then plug that in. It's a tedious calculation, but its the only way. Also, your equation $\xi^2_{,\nu} = 2 g_{\mu\nu} \xi^\nu$ doesn't make any sense.